# How Do I only reload one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with images. I only want to reload 1 image when I click on the context menu.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({

    title: "Does it work?", 
    contexts:["image"], 
    onclick: clickOrigin,

});
```

When i click on the  context menu `ClickOrigin` will be executed. But what code do I need so that `ClickOrigin` will reload only the picture i have right clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're going to be using `chrome.contextMenus.update(integer or string id, object updateProperties, function callback)` as mentioned in the [Google contextMenus guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus). It updates a previously created context menu item. Looking at the parameters that it accepts on onClick, it seems to accept, images, videos, and audio.